# What do you call it when you walk and a person in front of you is moving in your direction…

Tags: meaning, expressions, semantics

and both of you are indecisive in which side to swerve to to avoid bumping into one another?

Is there a word or expression that'll succinctly describe this sort of pedestrian dance off?

It happens a lot in social situations where 2 strangers try to pass through any sort of narrow passage and perform this little dance that usually cracks up a smile on both parties' faces?

Any input greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Alphonse-and-Gaston

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers. This is needed when answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.

Comment: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: I think *a word or expression that'll succinctly describe this sort of pedestrian dance off* is a reasonable description of what's wanted; and often enough the “example usage” sentences people create *don't* match any idiomatic way of saying the thing they want, and so becomes less helpful in creating an answer.

Comment: If anything, the needed answer may often include the word or phrase best describing something, *and* an example of how to use it. That's how we learn idioms, after all - from hearing or reading them in actual usage.

Comment: There are also several succinct answers, which are ***accidentally playing chicken***, ***[awkward hallway moment](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=awkward+hallway+moment+dilbert)*** (Google image search for "awkward hallway moment dilbert") or (from one of those strips) ***the “dance of the eye contact”***.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've scoured the internet for a bit and found it to be coined as a 'sidewalk shuffle'

Comment: Avoid posting answers that lack explanation, context, and supporting facts. A good expert answer includes this information to demonstrate that it is correct. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. In short, answers are expected to be lengthy and expert-level. Notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.
A better place for debate or free-wheeling discussion is our [chat] (or, when one exists, the chatroom attached to the post itself).